# Cg and OpenGL 3

Tags: opengl, shader, cg

I'm currently learning the differences between OpenGL 2 and 3, and I noticed that many functions like `glVertex`, `glVertexPointer`, `glColor`, `glColorPointer`, etc. have disappeared.

I'm used to using Cg to handle shaders. For example I'd write this simple vertex shader:

```
void main(in inPos : POSITION, out outPos : POSITION) {
    outPos = inPos;
}
```

And then I'd use either `glVertex` or `glVertexPointer` to set the values of `inPos`.

But since these functions are no longer available in OpenGL 3, how are you supposed to do the bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I'll recommend you to take a look at [the answer to this question: What's so different about OpenGL 3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492729/whats-so-different-about-opengl-3-x/3493412#3493412)

Secondly, Norbert Nopper has lots of examples on using OpenGL 3 and GLSL [here](http://www.nopper.tv/opengl.html)

Finally here's a simple [GLSL example](http://www.opentk.com/node/802) which shows you how to bind both a vertex and a fragment shader program.

Comment: But what if I want to use Cg syntax? :-/ (not because I prefer it, but because it's almost the same syntax as HLSL)

Comment: Take a look at http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=47. Also this post http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=267914 on the OpenGL forums.

Comment: Thanks, the second link is exactly what I was looking for