# gluLookAt nothing appearing

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I am using openGL/GLUT just trying to draw a primitive and use gluLookAt() to move the camera.  Having trouble and I am just seeing black.  Here is my code for the render function.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(Player.GetX(), Player.GetY(), Player.GetZ()-5,
          Player.GetX(), Player.GetY(), Player.GetZ(),
          0,1,0);



glPushMatrix();

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); //Begin coordinates


glVertex3f(Player.GetX()-0.5f, Player.GetY()-1.0f, Player.GetZ());
glVertex3f(Player.GetX()+0.5f, Player.GetY()-1.0f, Player.GetZ());
glVertex3f(Player.GetX()-0.0f, Player.GetY()-0.0f, Player.GetZ());

glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates

glPopMatrix();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

The Player.GetXYZ() values are all 0.0

Comment: Once you got over this, please do yourself a favor and move straight to OpenGL 3.0+. [Here is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492729/whats-so-different-about-opengl-3-x). [Here is how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293817/resources-to-learn-opengl-3-x).

Comment: Looks like your eye is beyond your triangle. Try +5 on the 3rd arg.

Comment: yeah just got that one :/ thanks!  Ok so I will try converting to OpenGL 3.0 before I am too deep thanks for the help.

Comment: FWIW, your code worked for me, but my initialization might be different. How did you setup the projection matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many major reasons as to why triangles are missing. The first thing you want to check is the depth buffer, to make sure that it is not a lighting issue. Many things can prevent your triangle from showing up in the depth buffer.

Make sure, you read through [Avoiding 16 Common OpenGL Pitfalls](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/). If you don't know the most basic pitfalls, you won't be able to properly debug your graphics pipeline.

If you don't have lighting enabled, you want to pay special attention to these:

1. Triangle clipping: Make sure, your player is at the right location, looking in the right direction.
2. Triangle color: You are not assigning a color. I think the OpenGL default is black.

If you have lighting enabled:

1. Check your normals.
2. Check your culling mode. [Back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling) is OpenGL default.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I can get the triangle to appear without gluLookAt() I just wanted to add camera movement.